# Why won't this image align horizontally in css using float properties:

Tags: css, joomla

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer me - I'm trying to get this page working for my charity's website. It looks perfect in every browser except IE. In IE, the long, vertical image that is supposed to float next to the other images is not aligning horizontally.

You can see it live here: www.worldofchildren.org

References an external stylesheet here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bannerincludes/boxes.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Here's the on-page code:

```
<div style="width:868px;">
<div style="float:left; position: relative;margin-left:25px; margin-top:20px;width:533px;"">
<h1 style="font-family: Adobe Garamond Pro, Garamond, serif; font-size: xx-large; font-weight: 500;
color: #0D9B89;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; line-height:90%;">meet the 2012 honorees</h1>

<div style="float:left;">


<div class="hover-div1" style="margin-right:6px; margin-bottom:6px; float:left;">
<img src="http://www.worldofchildren.org/images/banner/dallas.jpg">
<div class="hover-text"><a href="http://www.worldofchildren.org/honorees/393" style="color:#fff;">Dallas Jessup <br> 2012 Youth Award Winner</a></div>
</div>


<div class="hover-div2" style="margin-right:6px; margin-bottom:4px; float:left;">
<img src="http://www.worldofchildren.org/images/banner/craig.jpg" >
<div class="hover-text"><a href="http://www.worldofchildren.org/honorees/395" style="color:#fff;">Craig Kielburger <br> 15th Anniversary Achievement Award Winner</a></div>
</div>

<div class="hover-div3" style="margin-bottom:6px; float:left;">
<img src="http://www.worldofchildren.org/images/banner/alina.jpg">
<div class="hover-text"><a href="http://www.worldofchildren.org/honorees/396" style="color:#fff;">Alina Cho <br> 2012 Board of Governors' Award Winner</a></div>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<div class="hover-div4" style="margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px;float:left;">
<img src="http://www.worldofchildren.org/images/banner/dryoung.jpg" >
<div class="hover-text"><a href="http://www.worldofchildren.org/honorees/390" style="color:#fff;">Dr. Nilas Young <br> 2012 Health Award Winner</a></div>
</div>


<div class="hover-div5" style="margin-bottom:5px;float:left;">
<img src="http://www.worldofchildren.org/images/banner/kyle.jpg" >
<div class="hover-text"><a href="http://www.worldofchildren.org/honorees/392" style="color:#fff;">Kyle Weiss <br> 2012 Youth Award Winner</a></div>
</div>
</div>

<div style="float:right !important;">
<div class="hover-div6" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
<img src="http://www.worldofchildren.org/images/banner/benito.jpg" >

<div class="hover-text"><a href="http://www.worldofchildren.org/honorees/391" style="color:#fff;">
Beno&#238;t Duch&#226; teau-Arminjon<br> 2012 Humanitarian Award Winner</a></div>
</div>

</div>
</div>




<div style="float:right; margin-top:20px;margin-right:30px; ">
<h1 style="font-family: Adobe Garamond Pro, Garamond, serif; font-size: xx-large; font-weight: 500;
color: #0D9B89;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; line-height:90%;">15th annual awards</h1>

<p style="max-width:250px; font-family:helvetica;sans-serif; font-size:14pt;color:#777; font-weight:lighter; line-height:100%;">Join us as we celebrate the work of six exceptional heroes who have dedicated their lives to serving children in need. Much more than a ceremony, our Awards change the lives of those who attend and the children our Honorees serve.</p>
<br>
<center><a href="http://www.worldofchildren.org/awardsceremony.html"><img src="http://www.worldofchildren.org/images/banner/lm.jpg" border="0"></a><br>

Interested in Sponsorship Opportunities?<br>
<a href="http://www.worldofchildren.org/sponsorships">Click here</a>
</center>

</div>



</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any long vertical image at that link? Which do you mean?

Comment: It works now - comments below were helpful (added a width to the div instead of letting content determine width). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Put a width of `width: 420px;` on the DIV you have floated left (the first chunk of boxes). Even though it is floated, IE is giving it the full width of it's parent, so there isn't room for the boxes on the right.

Comment: Also very helpful - than you so, so much! I'd give you both a vote but my reputation is still too low. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a width to your floated containers.  Right now, you have no width and IE is filling the inline space with your left floated element.

To debug these things in IE, you can use the IE developer tools.

1. In IE, hit your F12 key.
2. In the developer tools, click the "mouse" icon in the top left.  This is your selector tool.
3. Will the selector tool, select the area of your website you are having an issue with.

In your case, you can see the floated left element is too wide, because it's width is currently dynamic.  IE is making it fill 100% of the horizontal area.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of float, this works in IE9

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```